# How do you avoid school Wi-Fi restrictions?

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, permission, vpn

I don't have the Admin Password or anything. But I want to use the Wlan at school without any restrictions. I also don't have access to the Network Settings on my Macbook. I use the MacBook Pro M1 (14", 2021). I would like to connect to a Proxy Server or VPN with the Terminal maybe.

Comment: At the very least, you'd have to do a lot of homework about networking.

Comment: This is not a Hackers "how to" stack.

Answer (score 3):

> How do you avoid school Wi-Fi restrictions?

#### You don’t.

Your device (MacBook, iPad, etc.) has MDM (Mobile Device Management) software that allows your school (network) administrators to control the configuration of the device including both the network(s) that it can connect to and what apps are deployed to the device.

In addition, your school network is likely configured to prevent unauthorized access by “rogue” devices.  At the very minimum, they are likely employing MAC (Media Access Control) filtering that will prevent unknown MAC addresses from connecting to the network.

From my personal experience, we employed something called 802.1x port based authentication for network access.  In other words, your device (MacBook, Dell Latitude, iMac, etc.) would have to successfully authenticate *before* it was allowed on the network.  So, if your school is using this, you won’t be able to bypass anything.

Finally, we’re not going to assist you in bypassing your school’s controls.  Remember, when you started at the school, there was an orientation in which they probably discussed “Acceptable Use” and what behaviors were allowed/prohibited.  Besides, there’s a basic tenet we adhere to:  Their network, their rules.